# Can't parse array to view in ejs node js

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I get array from firebase sever and put it into my array
than pass it to view. 
and view should how those array data one by one.

server code is as below.

```
    messageRef.child("store").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    for (val in snapshot.val()) 
        {
            arraytoapproval.push(snapshot.val()[val]);
        }
        console.log(arraytoapproval);

        res.render('showallstore',{flag:"success login",list: 
       (arraytoapproval)})

      });
```

arraytoapproval is well-formatted.

```
   [{ address: 'us-central',
    thirdImage: 'no' },
   { address: 'us',
     thirdImage: 'none' } ]
```

and view showallstore.ejs code is

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
        var initData = ('<%= list %>');
             ... 
             ...
```

I logged initData and says

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object]

I tried `JSON.parse(initData)`

but says

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Also, I tried `JSON.stringify(initData)`
but log says

> "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object]"

no difference except for `""` at first and the last.

I can't access any data in view eventhough I passed it correctly(at least I think)

Comment: I logged b and says  Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: initData is look like string value...I tried initData.length and says 192 which is a number of total character of [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: initData[0] is [....initData[1] is o...initData[2] is b..jajaja....

Comment: problem solved : var initData = <%-JSON.stringify(list) %>;